# Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the lesbesgue measure, show that there does not exist an $f$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the lesbesgue measure, show that there does not exist an $f$.

with $\int_{\mathbb{R}}| f |< \infty$ and  $\int_{\mathbb{R}}| f-1 |< \infty$

I have no idea where to start actually, the hint tells me that i need to show that functions with this property have:

$\lambda(x:f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2})$ and $\lambda(x:f(x) \leq \frac{1}{2})$ are finite

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Kees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such an $f$ existed, then set $A = \{x : f(x) \ge 1/2\}$ and $B = \{x : f(x) \le 1/2\}$. So  $$\lambda(A) = \int_{\Bbb R} 1_A = 2\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1}{2}1_A \le 2\int_{\Bbb R} f1_A \le 2 \int_{\Bbb R} |f| < \infty$$ and $$\lambda(B) = \int_{\Bbb R} 1_B = 2\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{1}{2}1_B \le 2 \int_{\Bbb R} (1 - f)1_B \le \int_{\Bbb R} |1 - f| < \infty.$$ Then since $\Bbb R$ is the union of the $A$ and $B$,  $\lambda(\Bbb R) \le \lambda(A) + \lambda(B) < \infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: i should prove this without that inequality....

Comment: I hope this edit clears things up.

Comment: thanks, can you explain the second inequality? f can be negative right....

Comment: On $B$, $1 - f$ is nonnegative because $1 - f \ge 1/2$ on $B$.

Comment: nevermind A makes sense because f(x) > 1/2

Comment: wish i could take you with me to the exams kobe ;)

Comment: @KeesTil hahaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20928/discussion-between-kees-til-and-kobe).